# Why we need to maintain our own matrices to transform Game objects?

Tags: c++, opengl, 3d, matrix

First, I think that I don't have complete understanding about 3D/Game maths. But I know C++ and OpenGL basics. Recently i have intergrated NVidia PhysX with OpenGL and worked well. So i can tranform my OpenGL objects using PhysX. Here is a part of my code,

```
NxMat34 pose = actor->getGlobalPose(); 
float mat[16];
pose.getColumnMajor44(mat);

glPushMatrix(); 
glMultMatrixf(mat);
-- draw the object --
glPopMatrix();
```

Bui i know that other people use separate matrices to represent their objects transformations even though they have physics libraries to transform their objects. My problem is why we need to maintain separate matrices/quaternions ? Can't we use Physics library's matrices?

Comment: Because each matrix represents a separate component (position, orientation, scale) of a "global" transform, that may evolve independently each from another.

Comment: Yes. but i'm asking why we can't use Physics library's matrices? They manage all the transformations according to its forces.

Comment: Hmm.. i can think about it. But, is it the only reason ? I can do it using library's matrix also. 
`actorDesc2.globalPose.t  = NxVec3(0,5,-10);
 NxActor * box = gScene->createActor(actorDesc2);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question presupposs that:

1. Everyone uses the exact same physics library. Or *any* physics library for that matter; many games don't need them.
2. Everyone uses exactly and only the matrices that come from that library. Animation frequently requires offsetting the position of the rendered entity from the "physics" location of it, not to mention having a different orientation. Or having *bones* (which are almost never part of any physics system) or other independent parts of the object.

You don't *need* to do anything. If you've got something that works for you, then do it. Just remember that there are consequences for every action. And in this case, the consequence is that you're directly binding the physics location of a game object to the location of the game object.

The tighter your code is coupled, the less flexible it is to needs down the line.

Comment: Animation is a good point. I believe there are lot of others... Thanks.